# Disk space not showing up

Tags: partitioning, nvme

I'm a new user of Ubuntu who has a little problem with my storage. I have Windows on an NVMe SSD and Ubuntu on an HDD of 750 GB, but I can't use the whole storage like it doesn't exist.

[image: terminal]

Comment: It looks like your hdd is sda but it only has one partition on it (sda1, 27.9G). The rest of the space may be unallocated. If you’re new to Linux, you might find it easiest to open the disks Utility to look at the sda drive.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of the terminal. Cut and paste the contents of the terminal into the body of the question. Also what version of Ubuntu are you using? Using the edit command add this info to the question. Thanks.